# How to make constraint for foreignkey in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I mainly work with Django but this issue I believe I can resolve only on Postgres level. I am a beginner in SQL, so that if question is elementary -please forgive me.

I have following DDL for users table:

```sql
create table users_user
(
    id           serial                   not null
        constraint users_user_pkey
            primary key,
    password     varchar(128)             not null,
    last_login   timestamp with time zone,
    is_superuser boolean                  not null,
    is_staff     boolean                  not null,
    is_active    boolean                  not null,
    date_joined  timestamp with time zone not null,
    email        varchar(254)             not null
        constraint users_user_email_key
            unique,
    first_name   varchar(30)              not null,
    last_name    varchar(150)             not null,
    user_country varchar(2)
        constraint country_code_within_list_of_countries_check
            check ((user_country)::text = ANY
                   ((ARRAY [elements of array are omitted for brevity])::text[])),
    master_id    integer
        constraint users_user_master_id_c8e42c6f_fk_users_user_id
            references users_user
            deferrable initially deferred,
    constraint users_user_first_name_last_name_622a9092_uniq
        unique (first_name, last_name)
);
```

`master_id`   row  here is foreign-key referencing same table.
Logical reason for this is that I want to  separate all users in this table to masters and slaves ( I am not support slavery but just for better understanding lets call them masters and slaves).
In this scenario master always have  `master_id field = null`, and `slaves` = integer(id of master).
For example:

```
user1, id =1, master_id = null   --master
user2, id=2, master_id = 1 --slave
user3, id=3, master_id = 1  --slave
```

Question is – is it possible to make a constraint or check-constraint ( 1 or 2 separated constraints, no difference) in a such way to suit 2 conditions:

**1) Slave can’t have it’s own slaves.**

**2)Master of the slave cant be slave himself.**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two foreign keys:

- `slave_id` points to the slave (can be NULL for masters)
- `master_id` points to the master (can be NULL for masters)

That is not very pretty because of the redundancy, but it allows you to

```
ALTER TABLE users_user
   ADD CHECK (master_id IS NULL OR slave_id IS NULL);
```

which would satisfy your requirement.